# Javascript not working in html inline code

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup

So, I use Angularjs, i;m trying to make a modal photo. but it does not work, the photo does not pop up if clicked.

Here is my html code:

> ```
> \<body\>
>     \<div class="center-content0"\>
> ```
>
> <div class="box-contentr">
> <img id="myImg" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/upmsi/image/upload/v1646621984/News/Features/eddy/P7040240_uzxrco.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:700px; max-height: 500px">
>
> ```
> \<!-- The Modal --\>
> \<div id="myModal" class="modal"\>
> \<span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'"\>&times;\</span\>
> \<img class="modal-content" id="img01"\>
>   \<div id="caption"\>\</div\>
> \</div\>
> ```
>
> </div>
> </div>
> </body>

js:

> var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
>
> // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
> var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
> var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
> var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
> img.onclick = function(){
> modal.style.display = "block";
> modalImg.src = this.src;
> modalImg.alt = this.alt;
> captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
> }
>
> // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
> var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
>
> // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
> span.onclick = function() {
> modal.style.display = "none";
> console.log(Chart)
> }

css:

> #myImg {
> border-radius: 5px;
> cursor: pointer;
> transition: 0.3s;
> }
>
> #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
>
> /* The Modal (background) */
> .modal {
> display: none; /* Hidden by default */
> position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
> z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
> padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
> left: 0;
> top: 0;
> width: 100%; /* Full width */
> height: 100%; /* Full height */
> overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
> background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
> background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
> }
>
> /* Modal Content (image) */
> .modal-content {
> margin: auto;
> display: block;
> width: 80%;
> max-width: 700px;
> }
>
> /* Caption of Modal Image */
> #caption {
> margin: auto;
> display: block;
> width: 80%;
> max-width: 700px;
> text-align: center;
> color: #ccc;
> padding: 10px 0;
> height: 150px;
> }
>
> /* Add Animation */
> .modal-content, #caption {
> -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
> -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
> animation-name: zoom;
> animation-duration: 0.6s;
> }
>
> @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
> from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
> to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
> }
>
> @keyframes zoom {
> from {transform:scale(0)}
> to {transform:scale(1)}
> }
>
> /* The Close Button */
> .close {
> position: absolute;
> top: 15px;
> right: 35px;
> color: #f1f1f1;
> font-size: 40px;
> font-weight: bold;
> transition: 0.3s;
> }
>
> .close:hover,
> .close:focus {
> color: #bbb;
> text-decoration: none;
> cursor: pointer;
> }

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks messy, i'm still new to posting questions. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Don't use `>` to format code. They're for showing quotes. https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/ may help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It's notable, that when correctly formatted, you can't post the question, as the ratio of the text and code is off. Please add some details to the text.